# What does %1 in "kill %1" mean?

Tags: bash, kill

I know that `$!` stores the pid of the last (background) process, but what does `%1` mean? I often see it together with `kill` and it has the same effect as `kill $!`. Can someone give me a hint? (Such small terms are so hard to google :-/)

Comment: Not really... http://www.google.com/search?q=percent+1+bash (see third result)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `%` designator refers to the jobs in the current shell's job list, and returns the PID. Try `help jobs`.

Comment: What was confusing me was that `man kill` gives the man page for an external kill executable which says nothing about `%`. But bash also has a built-in `kill` which as a built-in has precedence over the external `kill`, and `help kill` tells us that we can use jobspecs with the built-in `kill`, and that being able to use jobspecs is one of the reasons why it is a built-in.

Answer (score 10):

What you want to Google is [`man bash`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bash+1)

> There are a number of ways to refer to a job in the shell.  The charac-
>          ter % introduces a job name.  Job number n may be referred to as %n.  A
>          job may also be referred to using a prefix of the name  used  to  start
>          it,  or  using a substring that appears in its command line.  For exam-
>          ple, %ce refers to a stopped ce job.  If a prefix matches more than one
>          job,  bash  reports an error.  Using %?ce, on the other hand, refers to
>          any job containing the string ce in its command line.  If the substring
>          matches  more  than one job, bash reports an error.  The symbols %% and
>          %+ refer to the shell's notion of the current job, which  is  the  last
>          job  stopped  while  it  was  in the foreground or started in the back-
>          ground.  The previous job may be referenced using %-.   When  there  is
>          the  current  job  only, %- refers to the shell's notion of the current
>          job.  In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the  jobs  com-
>          mand), the current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous job
>          with a -.  A single % (with no  accompanying  job  specification)  also
>          refers to the current job.
>
> Simply  naming a job can be used to bring it into the foreground: %1 is
>          a synonym for ''fg %1'', bringing job 1 from the  background  into  the
>          foreground.   Similarly,  ''%1  &''  resumes  job  1 in the background,
>          equivalent to ''bg %1''.

**TL;DR:** `%1` is job number 1.

Comment: I thought quality was job number 1...

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Aye, that and the demands of nature.